# slowness when fetching query plan from cache plan for a given query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to fetch the query plan for a parameterized query from the query plan cache by running this `SELECT`:

```
SELECT qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st 
where st.TEXT = '(@p00 NVarChar(4000),@p10 NVarChar(4000),@p20 NVarChar(4000),@p30 NVarChar(4000),@p40 NVarChar(4000),@p50 NVarChar(4000),@p60 NVarChar(4000),@p70 NVarChar(4000),@p80 NVarChar(4000),@p90 NVarChar(4000))(SELECT DISTINCT [MyTable].[PROFILEID] FROM [MyTable]...[ETC]'
```

I did a `COUNT(*)`for the query above and it returns 5k entries.

If I run the query once in SQL Management Studio it takes around 5 seconds to return the result. 
If I run it more than once in parallel (for eg. 10 times) it becomes slower and it takes 15-20 seconds to complete.

Any idea why this query is so slow and how can I improve it?

Comment: Your concern is that your execution plan to get the execution plan is slow? Or the execution plan for the parameterized query?

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the query plan. I'm running the query above. The query is slow

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need to retrieve query plans in parallel and many times?